# Email sending in aspnetboilerplate not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtpclient, aspnetboilerplate

This is the settings:

```
AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.DefaultFromAddress, "abc@xyz.tech");
AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.DefaultFromDisplayName, "abc.tech Emailservice");
AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.UserName, "abc@xyz.tech");
AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Domain, "abc.tech");
AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.EnableSsl,"false");
AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Host, "webmail.abc.tech");
AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Port, "25");
AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Password, "gdfdgd");
AddSettingIfNotExists(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials, "false");
```

This is the email sending code:

```
// See "Update"
```

I am getting this exception:

> Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: This mail server
>   requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail
>   address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your
>   administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this
>   server

## Update

```
public class UserAppService // ...
{
    private readonly UserManager _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager _roleManager;
    IRepository<User, long> _rep;
    private readonly IRepository<Role> _roleRepository;
    private readonly IPasswordHasher<User> _passwordHasher;
    public readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public UserAppService(
        IRepository<User, long> repository,
        UserManager userManager,
        RoleManager roleManager,
        IRepository<Role> roleRepository,
        IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher, IEmailSender em)
        : base(repository)
    {
        _rep = repository;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _roleRepository = roleRepository;
        _passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
        _emailSender = em;
    }

    [AbpAllowAnonymous]
    public override async Task<UserDto> Create(CreateUserDto input)
    {
        // CheckCreatePermission();

        var user = ObjectMapper.Map<User>(input);

        user.TenantId = AbpSession.TenantId;
        user.Password = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, input.Password);
        user.IsEmailConfirmed = false;

        CheckErrors(await _userManager.CreateAsync(user));

        if (input.RoleNames != null)
        {
            CheckErrors(await _userManager.SetRoles(user, input.RoleNames));
        }

        CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();

        try
        {
            await _emailSender.SendAsync("test@gmail.com", "sdfs", "sdfsd", false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return MapToEntityDto(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: @aaron yes it is working with MailMessage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address.

Looks like an issue with your SMTP server ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22902100/8601760)).

Try sending an email to yourself or another user in the same domain.

> I can't send mail to other domains same domain it is working what will be the problem.

Contact the system administrator of your SMTP server.

> using smtp ordinary .net code it is working fine

You can send a `MailMessage` using `IEmailSender` too.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with aspnetboilerplate. as the error says *"This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. "*

Possible causes:

- Email client is not configured for SMTP authentication and the server
  is
- Firewall or email proxy software is preventing SMTP authentication from occurring
- Email client has incorrect credentials configured or does not match server settings.

What you can do is download the application below to test your smtp settings.
http://www.alexnolan.net/software/SMTPProber.htm

Once you send email successfully, use the correct settings in aspnetboilerplate.